# iframe in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, iframe, chrome

Referring content from this [SharePoint and iFrames (This content cannot be displayed in a frame)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joeric/2018/05/18/sharepoint-and-iframes-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame/), 
I have added allow framing in one of the web app in SharePoint 2013 to make apps work.

But now its giving error in SharePoint's layout page `Upload.aspx`. When I try to upload a document its not showing the modal pop up.

Error comes in only google chrome. IE don't have any issue.

Comment: try this for chrome - https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-enable-3rd-party-cookies-in-google-chrome-browser/ and see if the setting is on and if it works.

Comment: What error did it show when you uploaded a document? Does this issue occur on all libraries of your site collection?